# Sniffing the data around me

Tags: wifi, sniffer, sniffing

Scenario:
no router, just a laptop network card turned in monitor mode.
(imagine you are in the bus or train)

In this scenario can I see all the data that is going through air around me?

Can I capture this data?

Can I get some relevant info out of this data? (e.g. source and destination of the packets)

EDIT:

Can I sniff the traffic of other networks (other routers around me, and smarthphones) and get some relevant info?

what can I see? I should at least see the source and destination IP, but can I get some info our of this packets or the packets are totally encrypted?

This scenario is monitor mode? promiscuous would be when I am actually connected to the network I am sniffing? or do I miss something?

Comment: Are you actually connected to any network?

Comment: @Arminius no I am not. Is it possible to monitor the networks around you and capture traffic destinated to one device (smarthphone or router)? Without being connected to any network. Is it possible to extract any useful info in this scenario? e.g. if the people sends some plain text not ecrypted and so on....

Comment: Yes, if it's unencrypted. Why don't you try it, or read about it online?

Comment: Check out [promiscuous mode](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode).

Comment: @hashcode55 i thought that promiscuous mode is when you are actually connected to some network, or? I edited the question

Comment: @user155293 Promiscuous mode is when it's wired and doesn't necessarily needs to be connected to a network, the basic function of a NIC is that when it receives packets that's not meant to be received (wrong destination), it will drop it, in promiscuous mode (or monitor mode in wireless) means that it will accept all packets, even if they're not meant to be received by it.

Answer (score 1):

This questions is way too broad, try to be more specific, but **YES**.

If you put a wireless NIC in monitor mode it will capture everything within it's range (This depends on the antenna type, gain, position, etc.), from smartphones, tablets, AP, laptops, etc.

Now about all your questions you can do whatever you want to, but it is likely that most data will be encrypted, hence you won't be able to make much use of it.

Be warned that this may be illegal in different countries.

Related Topics:

- [Wardriving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wardriving#Legal_and_ethical_considerations)
- [Warchalking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warchalking)
- [Piggybacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piggybacking_(Internet_access))

Answer (score 1):

You can sniff one channel per NIC. Decent USB NICs are pretty cheap. If the data is sniffed from encrypted networks, you have to know/acquire the key. Dumping to pcap format lets you use pretty much any packet analysis tool to dissect traffic. Most of what you pick up is going to be useless data; HTTPS sessions etc.

Why do you want to do this?